# Spring Boot Autowiring Problems: Not An Managed Type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a repository class:

```
public interface WorkOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<WorkOrderDTO, Integer> {
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM workorder) Sub1 INNER JOIN (SELECT wo_number, GROUP_CONCAT(service_type SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'service_types' FROM service_type GROUP BY wo_number) Sub2 ON Sub1.wo_number=Sub2.wo_number WHERE fleet_company_id=?1 AND (order_status='On-Bidding' OR order_status='Draft')")
Collection<WorkOrderDTO> findWorkOrdersByFleet(Long fleetCompanyID);

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM workorder WHERE fleet_company_id=?1")
Collection<WorkOrderDTO> findWorkOrdersByFleet1(Long fleetCompanyID);
}
```

And an entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="workorder")
public class WorkOrder implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="wo_number")
private Long woNumber;

@ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id")
private Vehicle vehicle;

@ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "fleet_company_id")
private FleetCompany fleetCompany;

@Column(name="order_title")
private String orderTitle;

@Column(name="order_date")
private String orderDate;

@Column(name="order_time")
private String orderTime;

@Column(name="order_status")
private String orderStatus;

@Column(name="ref_number")
private String refNumber;

@Column(name="proposals")
private int proposals;

@Transient
private String serviceTypes;

public WorkOrder() {
    super();
}


public Long getWoNumber() {
    return woNumber;
}


public void setWoNumber(Long woNumber) {
    this.woNumber = woNumber;
}


public String getOrderTitle() {
    return orderTitle;
}


public void setOrderTitle(String orderTitle) {
    this.orderTitle = orderTitle;
}


public String getOrderDate() {
    return orderDate;
}


public void setOrderDate(String orderDate) {
    this.orderDate = orderDate;
}


public String getOrderTime() {
    return orderTime;
}


public void setOrderTime(String orderTime) {
    this.orderTime = orderTime;
}


public String getOrderStatus() {
    return orderStatus;
}


public void setOrderStatus(String orderStatus) {
    this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
}


public String getRefNumber() {
    return refNumber;
}


public void setRefNumber(String refNumber) {
    this.refNumber = refNumber;
}


public int getProposals() {
    return proposals;
}


public void setProposals(int proposals) {
    this.proposals = proposals;
}


public Vehicle getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}


public void setVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
}


public FleetCompany getFleetCompany() {
    return fleetCompany;
}


public void setFleetCompany(FleetCompany fleetCompany) {
    this.fleetCompany = fleetCompany;
}


public String getServiceTypes() {
    return serviceTypes;
}


public void setServiceTypes(String serviceTypes) {
    this.serviceTypes = serviceTypes;
}



}
```

and I have a pojo that extends the entity class:

```
 public class WorkOrderDTO extends WorkOrder {

private String service_types;

public WorkOrderDTO() {
    super();
}

public WorkOrderDTO(String service_types) {
    this.service_types = service_types;
}

public String getService_types() {
    return service_types;
}

public void setService_types(String service_types) {
    this.service_types = service_types;
}


}
```

I want to pass the POJO `WorkOrderDTO` to the `JpaRepository` instead of the entity for it to map column **service_types** which is not part of the entity class. But I have autowiring problems when I set `WorkOrderDTO` instead of`WorkOrder`. Maybe, it is some annotations problem. I didn't put any annotations to the POJO.

Comment: You can only map entities as the exception is telling you `WorkOrderDTO` isn't an entity and as such won't work.

Comment: @M. Deinum Some user here told me I can do this, if not. How can I get a column that is not part of the entity to be displayed using thymeleaf?

Comment: I nowhere said you cannot do it, you cannot do it the way you are trying now. I strongly suggest a read on how JPA works and how to have a query return a custom result .

Comment: @M.Deinum Would be of help if you can point out the link to the resource which explains what you have suggested.

Comment: @M. Deinum I think Srikanta is right. Maybe you can point out the link.

Comment: @Srikanta Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Lester There's a Google that gives you a link.

Comment: @RomanC Well, I tried searching. I just hoped that you experts has encountered more of this kind of problem. Thanks for being polite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the "new" Operator. You must create a constructor in WorkOrderDTO with the values you need, e.g.

```
public WorkOrderDTO(String serviceTypes) {
   this.service_types = serviceTypes;
}
```

then you can use it like that in a jpql - query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new your.package.WorkorderDTO(w.<select servicetypes somehow>) FROM workorder w WHERE fleet_company_id=?1")
```

However, I find your first query confusing, I think it is supposed to be a native query... There you can't use the "new" operator.

Maybe it is possible for you to map the ServiceType like Vehicle or FleetCompany as a List? Then you could concatenate just the values in the List for your DTO.

EDIT: You could use @OneToMany to map a List, as it is probably in your Vehicle class for WorkOrder, just to clarify my previous paragraph.

Comment: Should I extends JpaRepository<WorkOrderDTO, Integer> or extends JpaRepository<WorkOrder, Integer>?

Comment: Use JpaRepository<WorkOrder, Integer>

Comment: The problem is what I need is the first Query because it has the servicetypes, the second one just have workorders.

Comment: I think this may not work because I am concatenating as service_types. That's just a temporary column.